# Changing the default database for Rails to MySQL

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Im trying to use MySQL as a database for an application to which I updated the default database.yml file to

**development:**

```
 adapter: mysql
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: ***_development
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: ******
  host: localhost
```

**test:**

```
 adapter: mysql
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: ***_test
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: ******
  host: localhost
```

**production:**

```
 adapter: mysql
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: ***_production
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: ******
  host: localhost
```

`

But I dont see any .sql file being generated after trying to create tables from the console. Im a noob in Ruby on rails any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't be in your rails directory. You need MySQL installed on your computer and you need to create the databases in mysql.

Install mysql: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/installing.html

To access mysql through the command line:

```
$ mysql
```

or if you have a mysql root user:

```
$ mysql -u root -p
```

And enter your root mysql user password. Once you are in mysql:

```
mysql>  CREATE DATABASE db_name;

mysql>  GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON db_name.*
mysql>  TO 'username'@'localhost'
mysql>  IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

Obviously replace `db_name`, `username` and `password` accordingly.